# algorithm to round to the next order of magnitude in R

Tags: r

I apologize if the title is not clear, but I couldn't explain it succinctly.

Given a vector of concentrations, I would like to round the maximum value to the next order of magnitude (i.e., 345 to 1000). Also, I would like to round the minimum value to the lower order of magnitude (i.e., 3.2 to 1). These concentrations may also be below 1 so for example 0.034 would need to be rounded to 0.01.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not rounding, but something else. You can round 32 to 30 and consequently 30 to 0, but not to 10 or 1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not sure about R, but this is a simple process to describe algorithmically.

Take the base 10 logarithm of the number, and apply a ceiling or floor to the result. Raise 10 to that power. Done.

You need a special case for 0 because you can't take a logarithm of 0.

Comment: @Pocketsand in this case we're applying the floor or ceil to a logarithm, and we want consistent behavior regardless of whether the original pre-log number was above or below 1.0. Truncation would be inappropriate.

Comment: @MarkRansom you're quite right, I conceived of something mathematically impossible.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a simple function that does what you're after:

```
log10_ceiling <- function(x) {
    10^(ceiling(log10(x)))
}

log10_ceiling(c(345, 3.2, 0.034))
# [1] 1000.0   10.0    0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Hadley's `plyr` package has an extremely flexible function called `round_any` which does this elegantly. Here is how you would call the function

```
round_any(x, accuracy, f = round)
```

In your case, `x = 345`, `accuracy = 1000` and you want `f = ceiling`. So calling

```
round_any(x = 345, accuracy = 1000, f = ceiling)
```

would do the job

EDIT. Just saw that you wanted the `maximum` to be rounded up to `ceiling` and the minimum values rounded down to `floor`. change the `f` in the function call to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ramnath! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer by Mark Ransom is mostly correct.
Having implemented this in Java I have found some more areas that need to be addressed:

- Negative numbers need to be handled specially if you want -375 to yield -1000
- Ceiling for positive log values, floor **+ 1** for negative log values (the plus one is important if you want 0.456 to yield 1).

Here is my implementation in Java with passing unit tests

```
static double roundUpToNearestMagnitude(double n) {
    if (n == 0d) return 1d; 
    boolean negative = n < 0; 
    double log = Math.log10(Math.abs(n));
    double decimalPlaces = ((log > 0)) ? (Math.ceil(log)) : (Math.floor(log) + 1);
    double rounded = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return negative ? -rounded : rounded;
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeFifty() {
    Assert.assertEquals(100d, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(50d), 0.000001);
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeFive() {
    Assert.assertEquals(10d, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(5d), 0.000001);
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeZeroPointFive() {
    Assert.assertEquals(1d, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(0.5d), 0.000001);
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeZeroPointZeroFive() {
    Assert.assertEquals(.1d, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(0.05d), 0.000001);
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeZeroPointZeroZeroFive() {
    Assert.assertEquals(.01d, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(0.005d), 0.000001);
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeNegativeFifty() {
    Assert.assertEquals(-100d, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(-50d), 0.000001);
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeNegativeFive() {
    Assert.assertEquals(-10d, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(-5d), 0.000001);
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeNegativeZeroPointFive() {
    Assert.assertEquals(-1d, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(-0.5d), 0.000001);
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeNegativeZeroPointZeroFive() {
    Assert.assertEquals(-.1d, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(-0.05d), 0.000001);
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeNegativeZeroPointZeroZeroFive() {
    Assert.assertEquals(-.01d, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(-0.005d), 0.000001);
}

@Test public void roundUpToNearestMagnitudeZero() {
    Assert.assertEquals(1, roundUpToNearestMagnitude(0d), 0.000001);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to switch from `ceil()` to `floor()+1` for negative log values. Which case is fixed by this?

Comment: It may not actually need that @MarkRansom.  I'm not sure at this point.

Comment: I know, it's tough when you get a question for an answer you left 6+ years ago. But this is the first time I'd seen it, and since you called me out by name...

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested, the following is Ostermiller's solution translated to Python:

```html
def roundUpToNearestMagnitude(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    negative = n < 0
    log = np.log10(abs(n))
    if log > 0:
        decimalPlaces = np.ceil(log)
    else:
        decimalPlaces = np.floor(log) + 1
    rounded = np.power(10, decimalPlaces)
    if negative:
        return -rounded
    else:
        return rounded

def test_roundUpToNearestMagnitude():
    assert(100 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(50))
    assert(10 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(5))
    assert(1 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(0.5))
    assert(.1 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(0.05))
    assert(.01 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(0.005))
    assert(-100 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(-50))
    assert(-10 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(-5))
    assert(-1 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(-0.5))
    assert(-.1 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(-0.05))
    assert(-.01 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(-0.005))
    assert(1 == roundUpToNearestMagnitude(0))
```

Comment: This needs `import numpy as np` at the top in order to work.  Without that, you get `NameError: global name 'np' is not defined`.