# Java numbers, "human" rounding

Tags: java, rounding, rounding-error

I bet there was a similar question here on SO, I just could not find it.
The question is about fixing java math inaccuracy, when I get for example a number like `235.00000002` or `9875.999999997`. Sure as a hell, for a human these two actually mean `235` and `9876`, when a certain accuracy threshold is given, let's call it "5 zeros or nines".

But it's not only about the digits to the right of the decimal point, the same rule should also apply to numbers like `23500000001.0` and `5699999999.0`

Any ideas/libraries?

**Update:**
Looks like I was wrong saying it's a known topic and a matter of minutes until someone pops up with a known library. So here is the logic I expect:
For a given number when N consecutive zeroes or nines are encountered in its string representation, then these zeroes and nines are rounded together with the rest of the number to the right of the rightmost "0" or "9".
Foe example, when N=5, then the number `239999995.546` becomes `240000000.0`, the number `34.0000007` becomes `34` as well as `340000.007` becomes `340000`.

**Update 2:**
That's what happens when in a hurry or paying not enough attention to the question. Sorry. I'm talking about "human" rounding. A good example would be comparing the output of `df` and `df -h` on a linux box. As for "inaccuracy" I was talking about, please run the following code:

```
double d = 1000.0;
double mult = 0.12351665;
System.out.println(d * mult / mult);
```

The response is definitely not the one you'd show in a shopping cart. In my case the situation is even worse, it's not only the money I deal with, it can be anything - percentage, big numbers, small fractions, and all of them as a result of relatively heavy math computations. So I'm talking about the rounding that makes sense for a human.

I'm already done with the code, but there is still a chance that someone did it better.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an actual question here.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, and what prevents it to be the question?

Comment: You need a more accurate definition of your question. Try to define the general rounding rule (according to whatever requirements you have). Then, if you have any problems implementing it, publish it here and ask for help. Your question as it is now, is extremely vague.

Comment: Ok, got it, I just thought it was kinda obvious and well-known issue with a known solution. I'll rewrite the question.

Comment: what does it have to do with "inaccuracy", whatever you mean by it?

Comment: Why is `239999995.546` worse than `239989995.546`? But maybe something like this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906996/algorithm-to-round-to-the-next-order-of-magnitude-in-r

Comment: And I just realize your rounding rules are not consistent: Why does `240000000.0` keep a `.0` while `340000` and `34` do not? Also the scientific notation provided by Formatter `%e` might help you, it gives `2.400000e+08` for `239999995.546`

Comment: @SebastianHöffner, I've updated the question, again)) As for inconsistency - forget about `.0`, it can be omitted, it's just the way of showing that it still the double.

Comment: After your second edit I have to admit that actually the answer suggesting `BigDecimal` seems to be exactly what you need. The problem you face there has to do with floating point precision, it's nothing about formatting results or anything. Try `1000.0 * 0.123 / 0.123` and you will not have the problem with getting `999.99999` as a result.

However, you say you have the code done but maybe someone could do it better - how about you provide us the code and we can look if we can improve it?

Comment: My solution actually also seems to work fine with your example: `System.out.println(simplify(d*mult/mult));` prints `1000`.

Comment: I feel I still need to clarify my points here a little. My solution just prints as you requested. But to solve the problem in a better way is to follow the answer given by @Aleksander because it tackles the root course of your problem. Nobody ever said you should use `BigDecimal` only for currencies - and your examples "percentage, big numbers, small fractions" etc. fit perfectly into applications for BigDecimals.

Comment: @SebastianHöffner, sure i'd use the BigDecimal, but I never told that it's me who does the math, I receive these numbers via a web service which out of my control((

Comment: Okay, I think your calculation there was misleading, it implies somehow that you are doing the calculations and have to deal with problematic results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around a little with the scientific notation as I already suggested in the comments. Here is what I came up with:

```
public static double simplify(Number n) {
    String numberString = String.format("%e", n);
    int indexE = numberString.indexOf('e');
    String baseValue = numberString.substring(0, indexE);
    String exponent = numberString.substring(indexE + 1);
    double base = Double.parseDouble(baseValue);
    int    exp = Integer.parseInt(exponent);

    return base * Math.pow(10, exp);
}
```

I used all numbers I found in your question and added a negative value as well to test it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Number[] ns = new Number[]{
            239999995.546,
            239989995.546,
               340000.007,
                   34.0000007,
           5699999999.0,
                  235.00000002,
                 9875.999999997,
                -4334.345345,
          23500000001.0,
                    0.30000007,
                   -0.053999949
    };
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.#####");
    for(Number n : ns) {
        String s = df.format(simplify(n));
        System.out.println("    " + n + " is " + s);
    }
}
```

The results are:

```
2.39999995546E8 is 240000000
2.39989995546E8 is 239990000
340000.007 is 340000
34.0000007 is 34
5.699999999E9 is 5700000000
235.00000002 is 235
9875.999999997 is 9876
-4334.345345 is -4334.345
2.3500000001E10 is 23500000000
0.30000007 is 0.3
-0.053999949 is -0.054
```

**Edit** I adjusted the code to use double, fixed the error with exponents < 0 and added another example. Additionally I plugged in a `DecimalFormat`. Note that adding more `#` might change some results, i.e. `-0.053999949` will now show up as `-0.054`, with more digits it will result in `-0.05399995`.

Comment: Looks interesting. But what happened to `-4334.345345`, why is it changed?

Comment: The scientific notation is `-4.334345e+03`, the code grabs divides it into `-4.334345` and `3` and calculates `4.334345 * 10^3 = 4334.345` which is then cast to a `long`, hence the decimal digits get thrown away. Change the return type to `double` and you will get better results, though than you have to fight with lots of 0s after the period. edit: and for that there are already answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284938/remove-trailing-zeros-from-double

Comment: Ok, i see. Just tested, it's not working with `0.30000007` for example, but I think I get your idea, can fix it on my own. Thank you for your patience))

Comment: I checked it, try `+1` instead of `+2` for the exponent, I didn't think about negative exponents. I'll update my answer, also to reflect doubles.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to ask how to store and handle currencies. Short answers are: use the BigDecimal type or create your own currency implementation with separate integer fields for the Euros and Cents (or Dollars if ou prefer :) ).

Already explained:
[Using BigDecimal to work with currencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359817/using-bigdecimal-to-work-with-currencies)

[Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: It's actually not about currencies, it's about human-like rounding of the numbers.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand the question at first. I do after the update.

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask for ideas, how about this one: make N not a number of consecutive zeroes or nines, but a threshold at which rounding a number is still close to the original number. Then go from the least significant decimal position, rounding the number one position at a time, and dividing the number you get by what you had before. Stop if the ratio exceeds your threshold. Experiment with the ratio and border conditions at which the rounding looks good to you. Use BigDecimal to avoid problems with floating point arithmetic.